# Getting TINYMCE cursor value to insert text at that position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have a Textarea message box that the tinymce plugin is attached to..

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#id_message",
    mode : "specific_textareas",
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
      ],
  toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
  relative_urls: false
});
```

I have another non-tinymce textarea as well and to the right of the Textarea I have some line item elements with a given `value-type` attribute. When these are clicked on, it finds where in the Textarea the cursor is and inserts its `value-type` value into the current cursor postion in the Textarea, along with the brackets enclosing the value. The problem is that I can't get this to work with the tinymce Textarea since I can't great the ID of it because it uses IFRAME. Is their anyone to use the following jquery code to implement on a tinymce textarea? The setContent function looked promising but it wouldn't be able to find where the cursor is to insert the value.

```
$("ul.action_buttons li").on('click', function()
{
    var insert_value = $(this).attr('value-type');
    var content= tinymce.get('id_message')
    var content = $("#testing")
    var textBox = content;

    var textAreaText = $(textBox).val()

    var caretPos = document.getElementById('testing').selectionStart;
    var textToAdd = "{{ " + insert_value + " }} "


    $(textBox).val(textAreaText.substring(0, caretPos) + textToAdd + textAreaText.substring(caretPos) );
    $(textBox).focus()
    $(textBox).setCursorToTextEnd();

});
```